# Migration SVN to Gitlab

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, repository, git-commit

How can we migrate a project SVN to Gitlab ?
if we commit to SVN , will  be automatically change in gitlab  referenciel ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All the information you need is located on the following page: [GitLab Docs: Migrate projects to a GitLab instance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/).